# I find it difficult to get the right codes for the exact background design as in the attached image

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

[image: UI design.]I have this UI and if y'all can see the background, there is a purple top and the rest of the body is white. I have issues making this out. The purple part is little bit curve ( I was thinking of path, but nothing works ). Doesn't seem to work !

I tried using path, it didn't work. I have no idea right now.